# Is there a generic way to parse the LoginName property in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User instance?

Tags: parsing, sharepoint

It comes in the form similar to i:0#.w|domain\userName, but I just want the domain\userName part.

I can definitely just split by |, but just wonder if there's more elegant way to fetch the login name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the elegant way is

```
private string GetLoginName(string name)
{
     var manager = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
     if (manager != null)
     {
         return SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(name) ? manager.DecodeClaim(name).Value : name;
     }
     return name;
}
```

Check out
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/01/29/convert-claim-based-login-name.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using client model, but thanks for the share.

Answer (score 0):

I've just learned in my opinion a better expression to parse this.
Instead of using `Split`, it seems better to use `Substring(user.LoginName.IndexOf('|') + 1)`